# How to flush Protobuf-net writer

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I am using the ProtoWriter/ProtoReader classes to implement something similar to the DataTableSerializer included with the Protobuf-net source.  One difference is that after the initial transfer of the table contents all future updates are serialised incrementally.

Currently I'm not disposing the ProtoWriter instance until the program ends (as I want all future updates to be serialised with the same writer).  This has the effect of delaying all writing to the output stream until the internal buffer size of 1024 bytes is reached.

Should I be creating a new ProtoWriter for each incremental update?  Is there another way to force the writer to write to the stream?

Sample code:

```
    private readonly ProtoWriter _writer;

    private void WriteUpdate(IEnumerable<IReactiveColumn> columns, int rowIndex)
    {
        // Start the row group
        ProtoWriter.WriteFieldHeader(ProtobufOperationTypes.Update, WireType.StartGroup, _writer);
        var token = ProtoWriter.StartSubItem(rowIndex, _writer);

        var rowId = rowIndex;

        // Send the row id so that it can be matched against the local row id at the other end.
        ProtoWriter.WriteFieldHeader(ProtobufFieldIds.RowId, WireType.Variant, _writer);
        ProtoWriter.WriteInt32(rowId, _writer);

        foreach (var column in columns)
        {
            var fieldId = _columnsToFieldIds[column.ColumnId];

            WriteColumn(column, fieldId, rowId);
        }

        ProtoWriter.EndSubItem(token, _writer);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question. The flush method isn't exposed because internally it is not always the case that it is appropriate to flush, but I guess there's not a huge reason not to expose this and just let it no-op. On the other hand:

- it is already a lightweight wrapper around a stream: you could dispose and recreate
- or you could just keep writing and make full use of the extra buffering

Comment: My notification system tries to limit heap allocations as much as possible so it's a shame to have to dispose and recreate the ProtoWriter on each incremental update (i.e. potentially per cell).

Comment: @Slugart the simplest thing to do, then, is for me to simply make the flush method public; for now, you could actually hack into that method via reflection (perhaps using `Delegate.CreateDelegate` to expose it via an `Action<ProtoWriter>`).

Comment: @Slugart note that in a recent build I did quite a few things to make `ProtoReader` re-usable; I suspect it is time to do the same with `ProtoWriter`. But the first step in that: make `Flush` public

Comment: Cool, I'll check out the latest version and keep my eye on the repo for the `ProtoWriter` changes.

Comment: @Slugart I have to say, though: if you are writing to the same thing, the "obvious" thing to do is - just keep writing (unless of course you're actually writing to a NetworkStream, and the issue is that you need to frame to send)

Comment: I am writing to a `NetworkStream` and sometimes the data never reaches 1024 bytes and thus nothing gets sent over the wire.